# Problems losing ArrayList entries

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I'm currently designing a Pictionary game for my final project in my Java course. It uses a basic Echo Server to echo data from the sender to the receivers. Every GUI gets its own DrawCanvas, but only the artist gets to draw and everyone else watches.

All of the data for the canvas is stored in ArrayLists, one for the lines, one for colors, and one for line thicknesses. When the data is being sent, it is packaged into an Envelope and sent to the server.

The Envelope class is essentially (String key, Object data), so you can ID the envelope using the string and unpackage the data on the other end.

Multiple clients can watch the artist drawing with no problem. The artist canvas continuously sends points (via sendStartPoint() and sendPoint()) to the other clients, which is rebuilt into the canvas on the other end. However, if a client joins after things have been drawn, they need to be updated with all the canvas data, or else they will only see what is added after they joined. To do this, the sendCanvas() and loadCanvas() methods are used.

**The problem I have** is that even though sendCanvas() is sending all of the data, the client is only receiving the data for the first line that was drawn.

Other than what is in the DrawCanvas class posted below, this is the only other processing of data -- where the envelope is unpackaged.

I can post more code from other classes if it will help.

**Only other processing of the Envelope**

```java
if (e.getKey().equals("draw")){
    ArrayList<Object> data = (ArrayList<Object>)e.getData();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> lines = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>)data.get(0);
    ArrayList<Color> colors = (ArrayList<Color>)data.get(1);
    ArrayList<Integer> thickness = (ArrayList<Integer>)data.get(2);
    clientUI.draw(lines, colors, thickness);
}
```

**DrawCanvas**

```java
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> lines = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();
private ArrayList<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color>();
private ArrayList<Integer> thicknessList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private Color color = Color.BLACK;
private int thickness = 3;
private ChatClient chat;
MouseAdapter ma;

{ // Mouse Listener Block
    ma = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            addLine();
            lines.get(lines.size() - 1).add(e.getPoint());
            //sendCanvas();
            sendStartPoint();
            repaint();
        }// end mousePressed
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            lines.get(lines.size() - 1).add(e.getPoint());
            //sendCanvas();
            sendPoint();
            repaint();
        }// end mouseReleased
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            lines.get(lines.size() - 1).add(e.getPoint());
            //sendCanvas();
            sendPoint();
            repaint();
        }// end mouseDragged
    };
} // End Mouse Listener Block

// Stores all the data required to build entire canvas
public void loadCanvas(ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> newLines, ArrayList<Color> newColors, ArrayList<Integer> newThickness){
    System.out.println("RECEIVED CANVAS");
    this.lines = newLines;
    this.colorList = newColors;
    this.thicknessList = newThickness;
    repaint();
}

// Sends all of the data required to build entire canvas
public void sendCanvas(int id){
    System.out.println("SENDING CANVAS");
    ArrayList<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>();
    temp.add(lines);
    temp.add(colorList);
    temp.add(thicknessList);
    temp.add(id);
    try {
        chat.sendToServer(new Envelope("draw", temp));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("Error sending canvas");
    }
}

// Adds new blank line to hold points, updates attributes
public void addLine(){
    lines.add(new ArrayList<Point>());
    colorList.add(color);
    thicknessList.add(thickness);
}
```

Comment: What should be happening, is that the entire ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> should be held in the first index of data. If you look at the "sendCanvas" method in DrawCanvas, ArrayList<Object> temp is storing all that data, which is removed in another class using data as the name.

Comment: It would better if you could post *less* code, not more code. Can you create a [mcve]? We only need to see the code that's directly causing the problem. See if you can trim out the rest, even if the end program doesn't do anything useful. What matters is that you have a small program that does something you don't expect.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I trimmed down the code that is there to show just the important methods. I don't think anything else should be affecting the results, unless serializing and deserializing the data could have some effect.

Comment: @GeoDude, you've made some progress on the "minimal" part, but you don't seem quite to grasp the "complete" and "verifiable" parts.  We don't want a cut down version of your code; we want the smallest possible program that demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: @FarazDurrani No worries. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's a definite improvement. To elaborate on John B.'s point, if this bug has to do with sending and receiving data, then can you strip out all of the GUI-related code? Don't draw anything, don't respond to mouse clicks. If you currently click a couple of buttons to induce the bug, remove those buttons and write a `main()` method that hard codes the results of those clicks. Please read [the page I linked](/help/mcve), it goes into a lot more detail about creating a good MCVE.

Comment: For what it's worth, creating an [MCVE](/help/mcve) isn't just some annoying hoop we make askers jump through. The process of creating an MCVE can be very very helpful in debugging your code. If you do it well you can probably pinpoint just a couple of lines that don't work. It takes time, it's often not something you can do in just 5 minutes.

Comment: I would start with the dumbest question. How do you know if sendCanvas() send all the required data right before the failing point... or how do you know if line stored all the data that you need? Try placing some log or print statement to output that data before the error happen.

Comment: @pompanoSlayer Through the use of the Debug mode/breakpoints, it's quite easy to capture exactly what is leaving and entering the instances of the class.

Comment: @GeoDude That is true. If you capture the send data and receive data like you said but the receive data is only one line, then it is not your code. The echo server isn't passing it correctly. If you have not check the data before you start parsing it, then maybe the parsing is wrong as you think it is. 
These may sound very dumb but I maybe have done it countless time for not looking at the dumbest situation.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I made a small amount of progress towards a MCVE, so the GUI doesn't relay any data. There is only one class between the canvas and the server which handles the data. I also noticed something possibly significant about the bug. If multiple lines have been drawn when the canvas is sent, they will all show up on every client, however new clients will see only those original lines still. So it appears the data from is initial canvas request is sent to every client on the next requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make my program work. It doesn't provide an answer for why some data isn't transmitted, but just accepts it as fact and works around it.

As you can see below, I changed the sendCanvas() method to send every line in its own envelope.

```
public void sendCanvas(int id){
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("SENDING CANVAS " + i);
        ArrayList<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>();
        temp.add(lines.get(i));
        temp.add(colorList.get(i));
        temp.add(thicknessList.get(i));
        temp.add(id);
        try {
            chat.sendToServer(new Envelope("draw", temp));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error sending canvas");
        }
    }
```

Rather than have the DrawCanvas rebuild it with loadCanvas(), I updated the existing addLine() method as such:

```
public void addLine(ArrayList<Point> line, Color c, int t){
    lines.add(line);
    colorList.add(c);
    thicknessList.add(t);
    repaint();
}
```

I know it might not be the best way of resolving this issue, but I'm on a tight schedule and it works.